# Determine $\Bbb E[{\langle S \rangle}]$ where $S$ is simple symmetric random walk

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

Let $(Z_k)_{k \in \Bbb N}$ be i.i.d. with $\Bbb P[Z_1 = 1] = \Bbb P[Z_1 = -1] = {1 \over 2}$. Consider the process $S = (S_n)_{n \in \Bbb N_0}$ with $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n Z_k$. I want to determine $\Bbb E[{\langle S \rangle}]$ for $n \ge 0$, where ${\langle S \rangle} := (A_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}$ which is given by the Doob decomposition $X_n = M_n + A_n$ with $M_n$ a martingal, $A_n$ is predictable and $X_n := {S_n}²$ (*quadratic variation process*).

Comment: Any thoughts on the problem? What do you get if you compute $\mathbb{E}(S_n^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1})$?

Comment: I think that I get $M_{n-1} + A_n$.

Comment: @saz If you know how the solution works, please share it with me!

Comment: I do know the answer, I simply have other things on my mind on a saturday evening. Re your 1st comment: That's correct, but it doesn't help you. Try to use the very definition of $S_n$, i.e. $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n Z_k$. Write $$S_n^2 = (S_n-S_{n-1}+S_{n-1})^2 = (S_n-S_{n-1})^2 + 2 S_{n-1} (S_n-S_{n-1}) + S_{n-1}^2$$ plug this into $\mathbb{E}(S_n^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1})$, and then  compute each of the terms separately using $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n Z_k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating on @saz's hint, we can write
\begin{align}
S_n^2 &= (S_n-S_{n-1})^2 + 2S_{n-1}(S_n-S_{n-1}) + S_{n-1}^2\\
&= Z_n^2 + 2S_{n-1}Z_n + S_{n-1}^2.
\end{align}
Letting $\{\mathcal F_n\}$  be the filtration generated by $\{Z_n\}$, it is clear that $Z_n^2$ is independent of $\mathcal F_{n-1}$ and $S_{n-1}$, $S_{n-1}^2$ are $\mathcal F_{n-1}$ measurable, hence
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X_n\mid\mathcal F_{n-1}] &= \mathbb E[S_n^2\mid\mathcal F_{n-1}]\\
&= \mathbb E[Z_n^2 + 2S_{n-1}Z_n + S_{n-1}^2\mid \mathcal F_{n-1}]\\
&= \mathbb E[Z_n^2] + 2S_{n-1}\mathbb E[Z_n] + S_{n-1}^2\\
&= 1 + S_{n-1}^2.
\end{align}
It follows that the (predictable) quadratic variation of $X_n$ is
\begin{align}
A_n &= \sum_{k=1}^n (\mathbb E[X_k\mid\mathcal F_{k-1}] - X_{k-1})\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n (1 + S_{n-1}^2-S_{n-1}^2)\\
&= n.
\end{align}

It follows that $M_n=S_n^2-n$ as expected (since $S_n$ is a martingale).